# How to refresh the position of a datepicker UI when it's already displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have several input fields for dates in a form. The targeted data field name is displayed via placeholder which disappeares as soon as the input value is entered. For that reason I display the name in a 0px high div above and as soon as the input value is not empty I set the height of it to 24px. But the position of the poped up datepicker doesn't follow the input position.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="form-bg-1">
    <div style="height: 0px;transition: height 0.2s ease;position: relative;overflow: hidden;">Target Name</div>
    <input placeholder="Target Name" name="target_name" type="text" class="fomt-control date" maxlength="10">
</div>
```

Relevant JS:

```
async function placeholder_func() {
    if ($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val() != null) {
        if ($(this).prev() != null) {
            $(this).prev().css("height", "24px");
        }
    } else {
        if ($(this).prev() != null) {
            $(this).prev().css("height", "0px");
        }
    }

    //await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200));
    //alert('refresh');
};
$("input[type=text][placeholder!='']").change(placeholder_func);
$("input[type=text][placeholder!='']").keyup(placeholder_func);
```

I got it working by setting the top distance of the Datepicker, but i also realised the position is correct adjusted if i uncomment the commented lines. I would rather like to let the datepicker library do the refresh instead of handling the position myself. So how can i trigger a position refresh?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved it with using hide and show again. The input value gets cleared by the hide method, so i have to store the input value in a variable before. Still searching for a better solution though!

```
async function placeholder_func() {
    if (($(this).prev() != null && $(this).prev().css("height") != '0px' && $(this).val().length > 1)) {
        return;
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("date")) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $(this).datepicker("hide");
        $(this).val(val);
    }
    if ($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val() != null) {
        if ($(this).prev() != null) {
            $(this).prev().css("height", "24px");
        }
    } else {
        if ($(this).prev() != null) {
            $(this).prev().css("height", "0px");
        }
    }
    
    if ($(this).hasClass("date")) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200));
        $(this).datepicker("show");
    }
};
```